# Storing arbitrary objects in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, database, pointers, void-pointers

I am new to C but am trying to wrap my head around trying to store *arbitrary objects* in an array. Structs, integers, chars, functions, etc. Basically something perhaps using void pointers along the lines of (pseudocode):

```
void *array[] = malloc(10000);
struct MyStruct m = malloc(sizeof(m));
int x = 10;
char c[] = "Look Here";
array[0] = &m;
array[1] = &x;
array[2] = &c;
```

Essentially I want to have a global array store arbitrary objects sort of like a database, and then fetch them by index somehow.

```
void *global_array[];

void
get_from_array(int index, void *ptr) {
  *ptr = global_array[index];
}

int
main() {
  global_array = malloc(10000);
  struct MyStruct m = malloc(sizeof(m));
  int x = 10;
  char c[] = "Look Here";
  global_array[0] = &m;
  global_array[1] = &x;
  global_array[2] = &c;
  struct MyStruct m2;
  get_from_array(0, &m2);
  assert(m == m2);
}
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: You would presumably need a parallel array that records the size of each object pointed to be the `void*` elements of your `global_array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can create a void double pointer `void**` And allocate it space of (say 10000) void pointers with malloc. It can be indexed and it effectively acts as an array of `void*` type

For the code mentioned in your question, it would be something like

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>


void **array;

typedef struct MyStruct{
  int a;
  char b;
}MyStruct;

int main()
{
  array = malloc(sizeof(void*)*10000);
  struct MyStruct* m = (MyStruct*)malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
  m->a=1;
  m->b='x';
  int x = 10;
  char c[] = "Look Here";
  array[0] = m;
  array[1] = &x;
  array[2] = &c;
  printf("%d %c\n%d\n%s\n",((MyStruct*)(array[0]))->a,((MyStruct*)(array[0]))->b,*(int*)(array[1]),(char*)(array[2]));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio is it fine now?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Anything else? Really sorry for the edit where it didn't compile

Comment: No, as far as I can see everything should be fine. Additional, the OP wants furthermore to use a function `get_from_array()` to assign the object the provided pointer (in the argument list) point to but the design of it yet is susceptible for major issues if the provided pointer doesn´t match to the type of the object the relative pointer in the array point to. High-probably too much demand on you to correct this as you answered the main question already.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store many types, you need to save the size or the type of each variable. You should use the `struct` and `union`. For example:

```
typedef enum EltType { TYPE_STRING, TYPE_INT, TYPE_FLOAT } TYPE;
typedef struct Element {
  TYPE type;
  union {
    char  *str;
    int    i;
    float  f;
  };
}ELEMENT;
```

The test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum EltType { TYPE_STRING, TYPE_INT, TYPE_FLOAT } TYPE;
typedef struct Element {
  TYPE type;
  union {
    char  *str;
    int    i;
    float  f;
  };
}ELEMENT;

void print_value(ELEMENT elt) {
    switch (elt.type) {
        case TYPE_STRING:
           printf("%s\n", elt.str);
           break;
        case TYPE_INT:
           printf("%d\n", elt.i);
           break;
        case TYPE_FLOAT:
           printf("%f\n", elt.f);
           break;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ELEMENT elt1, elt2, elt3; 
    elt1.type = TYPE_STRING;
    elt1.str = "string";

    elt2.type = TYPE_INT;
    elt2.i = 5;

    elt3.type = TYPE_FLOAT;
    elt3.f = 1.2;

    print_value(elt1);
    print_value(elt2);
    print_value(elt3);

    return 0;
}
```