# How to dereference multiple layers of doubly nested pointers in C for a dynamic stack implementation?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stack, void-pointers

I am trying to implement a dynamic sort of stack in C. Here is the code:

```
void **x; // global database

void*
pop() {
  void *a = x[1];
  int *b = (int*)(&a[0]);
  int c = *b;
  void *d = ((void**)&a)[c];
  ((int*)&a)[0] = c - 1;
  return d;
}

void
push(void *d) {
  void *a = x[1];
  int *b = (int*)(&a[0]);
  int c = *b + 1;
  ((void**)&a)[c] = d;
  ((int*)&a)[0] = c;
}

void
init() {
  void **a; // this var can be ignored for this question.
  void **b; // this is the one I'm dealing with.

  a = malloc(sizeof(void*) * 100);
  b = malloc(sizeof(void*) * 100);
  x = malloc(sizeof(void*) * 10000);

  a[0] = (0);
  b[0] = (0); // it is a stack, but the first item in the array
  // is the size of the stack.
  // the stack is otherwise of arbitrary elements.

  x[0] = a;
  x[1] = b;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
  init();
  push(argv);
  char **a = pop();
  puts((char*)(a[0]));
}
```

I essentially just want to push the `argv` into the stack, and pop it out.

Then I want to log one of the items (or the whole thing, either way).

It's logging either blank or null depending on how I adjust the pointers. How do I get this to work?

Comment: It seems the code does not make sense. It is an awful code.

Comment: I'll ask [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159428/how-to-have-nested-double-pointers-without-structs-in-c): Why don't you want to use structs?

Comment: Can you answer with how I would do it with structs then? Is it not possible to do what I'm asking?

Comment: I want to do it this way because I want to not use any special objects but keep everything as low-level as possible.

Comment: If you can explain what exactly you want to achieve. If you just want a growing stack of void pointers, implement a circular buffer. If you want arbitrarily nested lists, implement your own types with tagged unions.

Comment: `&a[0]` leads to "warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer".  What is code trying to do here?  Surely `int *b = (int*)(&a[0]);` is replaceable with `int *b = a;`

Comment: Tip: 1)  there is no need for casts anywhere to do this task. For this task a cast implies the wrong approach.  2) Save time, enable all warnings.  Faster feedback than SO.

Comment: If you want nested lists (as was your request in the previous question) or lists that you can push to and pop from, you will have to implement your own data system. A good way to do that is with tagged unions: a struct that holds a type tag and then a union of type-dependent data. [Here's](https://ideone.com/a9cPDH) a very simple way this could look like.

Comment: As my answer in your last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156025/storing-arbitrary-objects-in-array-in-c/61156366#61156366

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica can you answer with your example? I can't see any way of doing this without using void pointers.

Comment: @LancePollard My comment was not to use [casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161251/how-to-dereference-multiple-layers-of-doubly-nested-pointers-in-c-for-a-dynamic?noredirect=1#comment108199929_61161251) like `(void*), (int*), (char*)`.  Using `void *` as an object type is fine.

Comment: @LancePollard Example `puts((char*)(a[0]));` could have been `puts(a[0]);`